# Allow specific HTML tags inside a text field of a custom content type using CKEditor

Tags: wysiwyg

I would like to add a new content type with a field which supports some HTML tags. So far, I added a text editor format and there I chose CKEditor as the editor and edited the list of allowed tags according to what I want to achieve. Then I added a new content type with a field of type formatted text. If I now add new content, CKEditor shows up where I expect it, but when I edit the source code and enter, for instance, an `<h2>` tag, it becomes a `<p>` tag after saving. The specific problem I'm facing is that I can't figure out how to "connect" an editor format to a field and make it selectable for the one who adds a field to a content type (for example inside the drop down menu where one can select the field type). Do you know any good documentation or tutorial which deals with this topic? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to "connect" an editor format to a field and
> make it selectable for the one who adds a field to a content type.

The text formats are shown in order here:

`/admin/config/content/formats`

The format at the top of the list is the default format.  To change the order of the formats, drag the arrow icon on the leftmost side and then press save.

Users can only see formats for which they have permission. The roles with permission are listed in the **Roles** column of the table at `/admin/config/content/formats`.  To change the permissions, click "Configure" for the relevant format and add the correct roles.

Comment: Yes, this is what is in core now. If you want to connect an editor format directly to a field you need this [core patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/784672) or the [Allowed Formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/allowed_formats) module.